# ActionFilterAttribute stopped working with IOperationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I've created an ActionFilterAttribute and it's not working with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IOperationFilter

**My custom attribute for mandatory headers:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyProject.Filters;

public class MandatoryHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _headerName;

    public MandatoryHeaderAttribute(string headerName)
    {
        _headerName = headerName;
    }

    public string HeaderName => _headerName;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderName, out var headerValue);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
        {
            throw new Exception($"{HeaderName} is a mandatory header.");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

**My operation filter to add dynamically the mandatory headers:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;

namespace MyProject.Filters;

public class MandatoryHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (actionDescriptor == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        operation.Parameters ??= new List<OpenApiParameter>();

        var mandatoryHeaders = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<MandatoryHeaderAttribute>();

        foreach (var header in mandatoryHeaders)
        {
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = header.HeaderName,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Required = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add the ActionFilterAttribute manually in startup, but it's still not working once I remove the swagger OperationFilter, it returns to work

**Startup**

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "MyProject",
        Description = "MyProject description",
        Version = "v1"
    });
    swagger.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
    swagger.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "swagger.xml"));
    swagger.EnableAnnotations();
    swagger.OperationFilter<MandatoryHeaderOperationFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionFilterAttribute is not automatically applied to your actions when using SwaggerGen. The MandatoryHeaderAttribute will work as expected when the actions are executed during normal runtime, but it won't be executed when SwaggerGen is generating the OpenAPI specification.

Manually Apply the MandatoryHeaderAttribute to Actions:

In your controller, apply the MandatoryHeaderAttribute to actions that require the mandatory headers.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [MandatoryHeader("X-Custom-Header")] // Apply the attribute here
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Your action code here
    }
}
```

To avoid duplication of header definitions, you can also modify the MandatoryHeaderOperationFilter to look for the MandatoryHeaderAttribute on the actions and generate the OpenAPI parameter accordingly. This way, you don't have to manually apply the attribute to the actions and keep the logic centralized.

```
public class MandatoryHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var mandatoryHeaders = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<MandatoryHeaderAttribute>();

        foreach (var header in mandatoryHeaders)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
            {
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();
            }

            // Check if the parameter with the same name already exists to avoid duplication
            if (!operation.Parameters.Any(p => p.Name == header.HeaderName))
            {
                operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                {
                    Name = header.HeaderName,
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Required = true
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification, the MandatoryHeaderOperationFilter will ensure that the parameters are only added once for each unique MandatoryHeaderAttribute used on the actions.

Now, when you apply the MandatoryHeaderAttribute to actions, it will work as expected both during runtime with SwaggerGen. The attribute will be fired, and the validation will be performed whenever the endpoint is called through Swagger or directly.

Comment: I've noticed it was working when calling the endpoint directly in any different way than Swagger, but I still wanted to have this action filter fired and the validation performed when the endpoint is called through Swagger. I didn't get the second sample with the operation filter you sent, it is re-setting the parameters for each iteration.